# ¿Como usar Node.js en asp.net MVC usando Visual Studio?

Tags: nodejs, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Actualmente tengo un proyecto creado asp.net MVC en C# y en el quería agregar codigo de Node.js.

Descargue del package nuget el Node.js y lo instale creándose en el proyecto una carpeta .bin que contiene node.cmd

Tengo el siguiente codigo en la vista que tiene extensión cshtml y queria empezar a probar el codigo de node.js:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Login</title>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="../../Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var http = require('http');

        http.createServer(function (req, res) {
            res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
            res.end('Hello World!');
        }).listen(8080);

    </script>
</head>
<body>
//codigo de razor , C# html, etc
</body>
</html>
```

Quería probar el codigo, pero no funciona. La verdad es que no he trabajado con Node.js, y por eso quería empezar a aprender e incorporarlo a mi proyecto ya creado.
¿Que debería hacer para que funcione Node.js en mi proyecto asp.net MVC en Visual Studio?
Saludos

Comment: NodeJS es un runtime enviroment para JavaScript o lo que es lo mismo un entorno de desarrollo para JS en el server; tu estas usando .NET por lo cual tu app va a necesitar de un server Windows para poder funcionar; te recomiendo revisar mas a detalle para que sirve cada uno pues no hay sentido en lo que tratas de hacer, crear un servidor nodeJS para ejecutar código C#? te repito tu requieres pero un servidor Windows

Answer (score 1):

Nodejs no se ejecuta en una pagina .html sino en un archivo js y tienes que tener instalado nodejs y ejecutar por medio de cmd windows o terminal linux o macOS ejemplo

```
//index.js
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
        res.end('Hello World!');
    }).listen(8080);
```

y en el terminal ingresar a la ruta donde se encuentra el archivo index.js y ejecutar node index.js

Comment: de hecho al asunto es que el compañero esta confundido al punto de que trata de usar NodeJS para ejecutar código backend C# el cual como primer punto no corre en Node sino en Wndows